# how to authenticate into google account service from web application for using google data

Tags: asp.net, authentication, service, using

Can some body please tell me the way to access the  google service such as the user feed items in google reader through the web application using username and password. I do not want the user to authenticate. I want the solution in ASP.net.

There is already a solution avaible in Python at http://dalelane.co.uk/blog/?p=303

But I do not know python.

Answer (score 0):

The python code doesn't do what you think. It requires a user to already be logged on.

See the link in the article you linked to here: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig.html#Requiring_Login_or_Administrator_Status

The user will have to authenticate at some point.